# Angular Directive does not exist on my component

Tags: angular, typescript

I've used a customized directive that will upload a file via drag and drop on my Angular app. apparently, the command line keeps giving me an error that my function does not exist on my component.

```
 Property 'fileBrowseHandler' does not exist on type 'UploadResumeComponent'.
```

I've seen one solution to add it on my exports in my app.module.ts but still, it did not work, what could possibly be the fix here?

(Name of customized directive = DndDirective)

Many thanks!

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  UploadResumeComponent,
  HeaderComponent,
  BannerComponent,
  SideMenuComponent,
  MainBodyComponent,
  FooterComponent,
  DndDirective,
  RhsWidgetComponent,
  ResumePreviewComponent,
  SkillsProfileComponent
],
exports : [
  DndDirective
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  [NgxDocViewerModule],
  PdfViewerModule
],
providers: [
{provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS, useValue: {}, multi: true},
{provide: CompilerFactory, useClass: JitCompilerFactory, deps: [COMPILER_OPTIONS]},
{provide: Compiler, useFactory: createCompiler, deps: [CompilerFactory]},
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

HTML FILE --

```html
<div class="upload">
  <div class="drag-area" appDnd *ngIf="!main.uploadedResume">
  <input
    type="file"
    #fileDropRef
    id="fileDropRef"
    multiple
    (change)="fileBrowseHandler($event.target.files)"
    hidden
>
```

Custom Directive (TS file) --

```
   import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
// import { url } from 'inspector';
import { ApiService } from './services/api.service';
import { MainService } from './services/main.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDnd]'
})

// @Input 

export class DndDirective {

@HostBinding('class.fileover') fileOver: boolean;

  // Dragover Listener
@HostListener('dragover',['$event']) onDragOver(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation(); 
  this.fileOver = true;

  console.log('Drag Over')
}

  // Dragleave Listener
@HostListener('dragleave',['$event']) public onDragLeave(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation(); 

  console.log('Drag Leave')
}

  // Drop Listener
@HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public ondrop(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();
  this.fileOver = false;
  const files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
  
  if(files.length > 0){

      //Do some stuff here
      // this.fileDropped.emit(files)
      this.getPreSignedUrl();
      this.main.uploadedResume = true;
      console.log("files", files)
      console.log(`You dropped ${files.length} files.`)
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add your ts & html code here as well?

Comment: hi @topmoon I added the html file where the error is happening and the ts file of my custom directive. Did not add my ts file of my upload-resume.html component since it was not used in this example

Answer (score 1):

`DndDirective` - this is your directive right?

Directives should be in the `declarations` section. If it's already declared in another module, import the module in your module.

**Update**

From your html code, the error is not related to your directive. Your `ts` file doesn't have a method called `fileBrowseHandler`.

Make sure to have it in your `UploadResumeComponent` component.